# Is h265 is supported in iOS8

Tags: ios

I'm read that new codec h265 is supported by iPhone 6. I'm wondering if this support is avaiable only in iPhones 6 or maybe in iPhone 5 with lastest iOS8?

Comment: check the doc Doc ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. On mobile devices it's the hardware that does the decoding. if iPhone 6 can decode h265 it's their A8 chip or another embedded chip that does the job. On iPhone 5s and lower, no decoding chip is available.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 6 don't have any hardware H265 support. It uses software H265 codec and that too only available for FaceTime on cellular network. No H265 video files playing and recording available yet.